# JSF do post and redirect with params

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have been reading a few posts saying that you can do the following:
Assuming this entry in `faces-config.xml`

```
..
<from-view-id></from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/xxx/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
..
```

an this `String` in the action implementation:

```
return "home?param=1&faces-redirect=true";
```

This does not work for me. It gives me an error saying that it cannot match the navigation case:

`Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/xxx/yyy.xhtml' for action 'home?faces-redirect=true&param=1' with outcome 'home?faces-redirect=true&param=1`

On the other hand if I use the full view name it works just fine. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing implicit and explicit navigation.

With explicit navigation, your code is supposed to return an outcome only. Whether to redirect or not should be encoded in the XML rule, not in the outcome which you return from your bean.

But as far as I know, navigation rules have no real use anymore. Just delete them and return the view with the required parameters and redirect options and such from your bean. When you have more then 10 pages you'll be ready to pull your hair out when you use navigation rules. (Ironically, navigation rules were created to manage large amount of views, but exactly with a large amount of views they become completely and utterly unmanageable)

Comment: So what you are saying is that I cannot use both. This will effectively bind my java code to the webapp i.e. if I change a view name I will need to refactor the code. Is there a way to keep implicit navigation and pass parameters as well?

Comment: @johnd indeed, change view = refactor. But you have to do that in both cases. Either XML needs to be refactored or Java code. One way or another the name has to change. IMO navigation rules just to "protect you from renaming views" is a promise that never worked out in practice. But it's your call and just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: @johnd you can specify the redirect via XML something like a redirect child tag or so. Navigation rules can use EL and you can probably pull the value from your (backing) bean using an EL expression pointing to a propery of it.